# django ModuleNotFound during deployment

Tags: python, django, apache, deployment, reportlab

- The error is here: http://18.221.170.83/
- When I run python manage.py run server, the all modules work fine.
- When using django + apache, no module named reportlab is found.
- I'm pretty sure I'm not using any virtual environments
- I followed this tutorial: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/django/get-started/deploy-django-project/ exactly, using the provided custom vhost config. It is below as well.
- I'm new to django, any suggestions appreciated!

```
 <IfDefine !IS_APPNAME_LOADED>
    Define IS_APPNAME_LOADED
    WSGIDaemonProcess elijahtai_homepage python-home=/opt/bitnami/python python-path=/opt/bitnami/projects/elijahtai_homepage
  </IfDefine>
  <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 _default_:80>
    ServerAlias *
    WSGIProcessGroup elijahtai_homepage
    Alias /robots.txt /opt/bitnami/projects/elijahtai_homepage/static/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /opt/bitnami/projects/elijahtai_homepage/static/favicon.ico
    Alias /static/ /opt/bitnami/projects/elijahtai_homepage/static/
    <Directory /opt/bitnami/projects/elijahtai_homepage/static>
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/bitnami/projects/elijahtai_homepage/elijahtai_homepage/wsgi.py
    <Directory /opt/bitnami/projects/elijahtai_homepage/elijahtai_homepage>
      <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
      </Files>
    </Directory>
```

I tried adding it to 'installed_apps' in the settings file, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Somehow, installing that with sudo made it work (ie pip uninstall reportlab, sudo pip install reportlab.)